# write persisted keras model to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, keras, bucket

I ran an lstm model in keras and persisted it to a json object. 
I want to write this json object directly to an s3 bucket. Boto3 tutorials really don't cover this, they only show how to write files to s3. I really need to be able to store keras models in json directly from python (in memory) to s3. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

As there is only one other answer to this question, please note that `model.to_json()` saves only the model architecture and the *initialized* weights but NOT the *trained* weights. Unfortunately the keras API documentation is not clear on this, but if you load a model using `model_from_json` it will run, but using the initial weights. Therefore the  output of your model will likely be nonseniscal.

There does not currently appear to be a simple way to write model files directly from memory (although have a look at the example [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/11708)).

In order to save the model with trained weights use the method to save model objects proposed in the keras [documentation](https://keras.io/api/models/model_saving_apis/).

```
from keras.models import load_model
import boto3

model.save('my_model.h5')  # creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'
client = boto3.client('s3')
client.upload_file(Filename='my_model.h5',
                  Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
                  Key='my_model.h5')

del model  # deletes the existing model
```

To download the model and load it:

```
client.download_file(BUCKET_NAME,
                     'my_model.h5',
                     'my_model.h5')
# returns a compiled model
# identical to the previous one
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

You can then delete the file again if you do not want to save it locally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Client.put_object()](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) to write to an S3 object directly without saving to and uploading a file. Here's a concrete example:

```
import boto3

# Convert your existing model to JSON
saved_model = model.to_json()

# Write JSON object to S3 as "keras-model.json"
client = boto3.client('s3')
client.put_object(Body=saved_model,
                  Bucket='BUCKET_NAME',
                  Key='keras-model.json')
```

You can then download the `keras-model.json` and then load it back into a Keras model like this using `model_from_json`.

```
from keras.models import model_from_json

# Read the downloaded JSON file
with open('keras-model.json', 'r') as model_file:
   loaded_model = model_file.read()

# Convert back to Keras model
model = model_from_json(loaded_model)

# Confirmation
model.summary()
```

Comment: This answer is misleading, as "model_from_json" does not do what is suggested. It loads initial (random) but not the trained weights. Please clarify or delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this even for the h5 type through the [h5py](https://pypi.org/project/h5py/) library.

For trained models, the h5 type is necessary as it includes the weights. The json version does not, as explained above.

```
import io
import h5py
import boto3

# Create bytes io as target.
with io.BytesIO() as model_io:
    # Instanciate h5 file using the io.
    with h5py.File(model_io, 'w') as model_h5:
        # Save the Keras model to h5 object (and indirectly to bytesio).
        model.save(model_h5)
        # Make sure the data is written entirely to the bytesio object.
        model_h5.flush()
    # Upload to S3.
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    client.put_object(
        Bucket='BUCKET_NAME',
        Key='keras-model.h5',
        Body=model_io,
    )
```

I did not test this exact snippet, but I am have used something along these lines before and it worked.